# Flask Sqlalchemy that works with postgres 9.6

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have been trying to deploy my flask application in a raspbian os environment. The application was running smoothly on ubuntu and postgres 11. On trying to run sqlalchemy migration i encountered error:  undefined symbol: PQencryptPasswordConn. I later found out that the missing library was added on postgres 10 and later versions hence missing in versions which were earlier before version 10. I cannot install version 10 or above on raspbian since it is yet to be supported. My only options are installing ubuntu core on my raspberry or find a  Flask-SQLalchemy version that works with postgres 9.6. If anyone has been in my situation before or has a better idea your advice will be very much appreciated

Comment: include an odbc driver in the sqlalchemy connection string that is compatible with the version of postres you're using. my recommendation is pyodbc since it is the best supported odbc package for python imo.

Comment: Will try that. Thank you. I had already given up and installed ubuntu core but the it is not as lightweight as raspian. Will try this on a VM or docker image and if it works will go back to raspian